# Best way to use IF statements

Tags: javascript, performance

Assume I've 10 columns in AG-Grid, I need to update the certain column fields to non editable based on few conditions.

Below code works, but I would like to do it in a better way.

Note: Only on the click event I'll get the column ID.

```
 if (event.column.colId === 'xxx' || event.column.colId === 'yyy' || event.column.colId === 'xx' || event.column.colId === 'yy'
        || event.column.colId === 'dd' || event.column.colId === 'mm' || event.column.colId === 'yy' || event.column.colId === 'cc' || event.column.colId === 'vv') {
        event.colDef.editable = false;
      }
```

Comment: I vote to close this as off-topic, because this belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com and not so Stack Overflow. You will find help there. :)

Comment: @CodeF0x Doubt it, this code is stripped of all context.

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a array with the values you need to compare and then use `indexOf()` method of array to check if the `event.column.colId` has value as specified in the array or not.

```
var match = ['xxx', 'yyy', 'xx', 'yy', 'dd', 'mm', 'cc', 'vv']; 
if (match.indexOf(event.column.colId) !== -1) {
    event.colDef.editable = false;
}
```

You can also use `if(match.includes(event.column.colId))` which returns a boolean value but `includes()` do not work in IE browser so I recommend to use `indexOf()`

> The **indexOf()** method returns the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at fromIndex. Returns `-1` if the value is not found.

Answer (score 1):

A more appropriate collection for this job might be a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). In most cases, the difference in performance alone shouldn't bother you, but this collection will typically be implemented as a hash table and therefore more performant for large sets (provided that don't initialize it in each iteration, of course).

Nevertheless, it's semantically the right collection for storing unique values and demonstrates your intent more clearly IMHO.

Usage is pretty straightforward:

```
const match = new Set(['xxx', 'yyy', 'xx', 'yy']);

// O(1) time complexity, most likely
if (match.has('yy')) {
     // do stuff
}
```

If you don't want to use a `Set` or need to support older browsers without using a polyfill, you can use a plain js object to get the same hashing performance benefits:

```
function init(a) {
  var result = {};
  for (var i = 0, length = a.length; i < length; i++) {
    result[a[i]] = true;
  }
  return result;
}

var match = init(['xxx', 'yyy', 'xx', 'yy']);
if (match.hasOwnProperty('yy')) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array:

```
const colIds = ['xxx', 'yyy', 'xx', 'yy']; //etc.

if (colIds.indexOf(event.column.colId) > -1) {
  event.colDef.editable = false;
}
```